# Show image uploaded in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed this tutorial http://ryan.endacott.me/2014/06/10/rails-file-upload.html

to make an upload images without using gems .
But it does not teach how to display the image.I 've tried several ways , but without success.

Comment: that tutorial links to an example app with a working index view that has download links for the documents: https://github.com/ryan-endacott/Rails-File-Upload-Example/blob/master/app/views/documents/index.html.erb

Comment: I know, but in the tutorial it teaches only downloading, does not teach how to display an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to add `disposition: "inline"` to the `send_data` method as well as the `type` of file in order to display an image instead of downloading it, as documented here. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

```
def show
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])

  send_data(@document.file_contents,
        type: @document.content_type,
        filename: @document.filename,
        type: 'image/png',
        disposition: "inline")
end
```

Then in whatever/your/path/is/show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag url_for(controller: "documents", 
                  action: "show", 
                  id: @document.id) %>
```

This article may be helpful (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rails-cookbook/0596527314/ch15s04.html):

> For a browser to display binary image data, it needs to be instructed that the data is an image. Specifically, it needs to be told that the content type of the data is something like image/gif. Providing a filename gives the browser something to name the data, should it be downloaded and saved by the user. Finally, the disposition specifies whether the file will be displayed inline or downloaded as an attachment. If its disposition is not specified, it’s assumed to be an attachment.

I hope that helps!